# pivoting large table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I'd like to pivot a table, similar to the one below

[image]

to display as follows

[image]

The actual table I'm using has over 1.6 million rows, and 1500+ fields, mostly with non-boolean answers.Most of the solutions I've found require me to specify what the Field Answer contents will be in the query, which is not feasible, given the number of fields and variety of field answers. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at https://postgresql.verite.pro/blog/2018/06/19/crosstab-pivot.html . Because it is not feasible for you to enumerate the Field answer contents, you'll need a "dynamic" pivot, not a static one.

Comment: the only answer is to use dynamic sql

Comment: One substantial limitation of SQL is, that the number, name and data type of all columns of a result must be known to the database engine before the query is executed (i.e. at parse time). With that many columns, I would suggest aggregating that into a JSON value. 1500+ columns is very close to the maximum number of columns a query can return, so this might not be doable at all.

Comment: Assuming that I'm working with the table posted here, and I know the number (4), name (ID, Field 1, Field 2, Field 3), and data types of all columns(boolean), how would you write this query?