# pivoting large table in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, pivot, transform

I'd like to pivot a table, similar in structure to the one below:

[image]

To display as follows:

[image]

The actual table I'm using has over 1.6 million rows, and 1500+ different field values (field 1, field 2, field 3, etc) currently in the Field column. The goal is to pivot the contents to make the table less unwieldy to work with. The `Field_Answers` are mostly of the `Long-Text` data type, which seems to be a problem, as I am getting the error:

> "Cannot have Memo or OLE Object fields in aggregate argument"

I'm currently trying to use the query below, which returns the above-stated error:

```
TRANSFORM Max(mytable.FieldAnswer)

SELECT mytable.ID
FROM mytable

GROUP BY mytable.ID

PIVOT mytable.Field
```

Comment: Do you actually need to have more than the first 255 characters? Else you could just `TRANSFORM Max(LEFT(mytable.FieldAnswer, 255))` to truncate the field to a short text field. If you need more than 255 characters, then you can't pivot in Access itself (but can export to Excel/SQL Server/etc. and do the pivoting there).

Comment: I do need more than the first 255 characters. I wanted to do this in Postgresql, but was met with the following when I posed the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65587003/pivoting-large-table-in-postgresql?noredirect=1#comment115961407_65587003 It doesn't seem feasible given the variety of the Field Answer contents...

Comment: I'd probably go Excel + PowerPivot for this, PowerPivot is supposed to be... powerful at pivoting.

Comment: Even if you get past the long text issue, it still won't work. You can't have more than 255 columns in Access.

Comment: A result table with 1500+ columns, each having >255 chars, would still be extremely unwieldy. I think you need to come up with a divide-and-conquer approach here.